# What's the measure of the side BC of the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the triangle $ABC$, the heights $BE$ and $CD$ are drawn. If $AC \cdot CE= 88$ and $AB \cdot BD= 108$.
> Calculate $BC$ (Answer:$14$)

My progress:
[image]

$AC\cdot CE = 88 \rightarrow b \cdot n =88 \\
AB \cdot BD = 108 \rightarrow c \cdot BD = 108\\
\triangle ABE\sim \triangle ACD \implies\\
\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BE}{CD}=\frac{AE}{AD}\rightarrow \frac{c}{b}=\frac{h}{p}=\frac{m}{AD}\\
\triangle CDB:: p^2+BD^2 = a^2\\
\triangle CDA: DA^2+p^2=b^2\\
a^2-BD^2 =b^2-AD^2 \\
\text{T.Poncelet} \triangle ACD-ED\\
m\cdot CH \cdot BD = n \cdot HD \cdot c\implies\\
\text{T.Poncelet} \triangle ABE-DC\\
AD \cdot BH \cdot n =BD \cdot EH \cdot b$

but I can't equate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $ACFD$ and $ABFE$ are concyclic. So by the power of the points $C$ and $B$ we have $$CF\cdot CB= AC\cdot CE = 108$$ and $$BF\cdot CB= BD\cdot BA = 88$$
so $$BC ^2 = BF\cdot CB + CF\cdot CB = 88+108 = 196$$ and thus $BC = 14$.

Answer (score 1):

As $ \small BDEC$ is cyclic, $ \small HE \cdot BH = CH \cdot HD$ and as $ \small ADHE$ is cyclic, $ \small BH \cdot BE = BD \cdot AB, CH \cdot CD = CE \cdot AC$. We will use them in our work below.

$$ \small \begin {aligned}
BC^2 & = BE^2 + CE^2 \\
& = (BH+HE) \cdot BE + CE^2 \\
& = BH \cdot BE + HE \cdot (BH+HE) + CE^2 \\
& = BH \cdot BE + HE \cdot BH + HE^2 + CE^2 \\
& = BH \cdot BE + HE \cdot BH + CH^2 \\
& = BD \cdot AB + CH \cdot (HD + CH) \\
& = BD \cdot AB + CH \cdot CD \\
& = BD \cdot AB + CE \cdot AC \\
\end {aligned}
$$

Comment: letter puzzle :) but interesting resolution,,thanks..